# Rewiring a small appliance

Tags: wiring

I have a small appliance with a 110vac transformer that broke off where I cannot reconnect it.  Can I replace that 110vac transformer with a 120vac and does it matter which side the wires go on?  Can I miswire?

Comment: This question,  while obvious to your situation, could also potentially describe many other situations. More detail or pictures will help greatly.

Comment: Don’t know how to upload photos yet.

Answer (score 1):

The transformer can be replaced, 120 /110v transformers are the same thing just different dates when they were manufactured. For many years we called line voltage 110, later 115 now 120 so they by definition are the same to the national electric code in the US. The important part is the output voltage and the size or how many amps / watts it is rated for. The new transformer needs to be rated the same or larger for example 120/24vac at 5 amps the new one needs to be 5 amps or better. The voltage needs to be the same in this case 24v I chose this as it is a very common size.

Can you wire them backwards, Yes if wired backwards where the secondary leads are tied to the mains or 120v the out put will be 600v if the insulation holds up (for this example).
Usually step down transformers have a ground wire on the primary side, most of the time they are stamped with the voltage on each side of the case 2 wires of the same color on the 120v side means it doesn’t matter which one connects to the hot and neutral or normally black and white of the 120v supply.

So make sure your output voltage on the secondary of the transformer is the same as the original and that it is rated for the same load in amps or KW, if the same value is not available go bigger NEVER smaller. And last make sure to hook up the primary side to the supply or mains voltage.

Comment: No markings at all on these transformers....info on label is exactly the same except for the 110vac and 120vac.  Class 2 transformer, input 110vac, 60hz, 48 W, output 24vac 833 m 8.  Wire on 120 transformer are thinner than 110 transformer.  Novice here....do you think it matters which side I connect wires to?

Comment: Looking closely at the wires 1 transformer has a wire with a solid white line stamped on the insulation and a solid black insulated wire..the other transformer has a wire withe a broken white line imprinted  one insulated side while the other side has info printed on it like 300v and other too small to read.

Comment: The white mark on the wire is usually used as the neutral the solid black as the hot. If the other side is screw terminals this is usually the secondary, this way the dangerous 120v lines are safe from being touched,  I am trying to follow since you said 1 transformer has the solid white and the other has a dashed white these should be the primary or 120v connections with the solid black to the black of the branch circuit, then the black with the white stripe to the white wire of the branch circuit supplying the circuit, a bare copper should be attached to the case of the transformer